# Why do I get error trying to cast np.array(some_list) ValueError: could not broadcast input array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create np.array of np.arrays of different shape. I need it because in the next part I will sum up this large np.array with some delta_array that has the same shape. 
Like matrices sum
     `self.weights += delta_weights`
And I will be working with each array inside it separately as well. Or for example I will need to multiply element wise all arrays by some number.

Can't figure out what's wrong :( Please, help me.
Code creates list of random np.arrays of different shape.
So here is my code:

```
weights = []
for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
    weights.append(np.random.rand(self.layers[i-1] + 1, self.layers[i]))
print(type(weights))
print([(type(w), w.shape) for w in weights])
#error here with layers = [2,2,1] or [3,3,1] etc
self.weights = np.array(weights)
```

Output:
For self.layers=[2, 2, 1]

```
<class 'list'>
[(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (3, 2)), (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (3, 1))]
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 20, in <module>
 run()
line 8, in run
 net.init_weights()
line 71, in init_weights
 self.weights = np.array(weights)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (3)
```

For [2, 3, 1] everything is okay:

```
<class 'list'>
[(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (3, 3)), (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (4, 1))]
```

For [3, 3, 1] same story as for [2, 2, 1] - error

For [3, 7, 1] or [3, 2, 1] everything is okay.

//It's matrices of weights for gradient descent for machine learning.

Comment: Does [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) help?

Comment: @Evert No. It will fail on layers=[3, 2, 1] and even if it worked then I wouldn't be able to iterate over arrays without additional code

Comment: I just tried this in Python3 with 1.8.2 numpy, and `[2,2,1]` worked fine.

Comment: What is your `numpy` version?

Comment: @hpaulj 1.9.0 http://cs624829.vk.me/v624829429/88ed/hqbhQlrTdaM.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you're trying to create an array of matrices, so that you can use array operations (like `+=`) later on.

You can declare an `ndarray` to hold another `ndarray`, and then fill it with the matrices (which are simply two dimensional ndarrays):

```
weights = np.empty(len(self.layers), dtype=np.ndarray)
for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
    weights[i] = np.random.rand(self.layers[i-1] + 1, self.layers[i])
```

Keep in mind that this is definitely not a three dimensional array: it's purely an array of two dimensional arrays.

The reason your code works for `[2, 3, 1]` is that the array with one dimension of 1 gets broadcasted; that's purely accidental, and not what you want, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

When you give `np.array` a list of arrays, it tries to combine them into one array (with a higher `ndim`).  Only if it can't combine them will it create an array of dtype `object` with one array in each slot.

In the `[2,3,1]` case the 2 arrays are `(3,3)` and `(4,1)`.  Since there's no way to 'stack' these, it creates a 2 element array containing these 2.

In the `[3,3,1]` case the 2 arrays are `(4,3)` and `(4,1)`.  Due to an overlap in dimensions (4 rows) it appears to be trying to join them into one array, possibly `(2,4,?)`, but isn't quite succeeding.  In your version it raises an error, in my version it creates a `(2,4)` array of Nones.

Evert's solution is a general purpose one that correctly handles these confusing case.  It works even if the 2 arrays in `weights` were the same size.

Say, for example if your `weights` contained 2 `(4,3)` arrays.  `np.arrays(weights)` would produce a `(2,4,3)` array.  Evert's solution would still produce a `(2,)` array containing 2 `(4,3)` arrays.

Looks like there's a bug (or two) in different `numpy` versions.  Python3 with 1.8.0 numpy handled the `[2,2,1]` case just fine.

A simpler test case would be:

```
np.array([np.ones((2,2)), np.zeros((2,1))])
```

Playing around the dimensions of the 2 arrays.  It should produce a 2 element array in most cases, and a `(2,n,m)` array if the 2 dimensions are the same.