# Creating numpy array problem ( could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1) )

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

what's the problem with creating this numpy array

```
np.array( [np.array([1]), np.array([ [1,2] ])] )

# Error: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)
```

but no problem with this

```
np.array( [np.array([1]), np.array([ [1,2], [1,2] ])] )
```

what's the problem with creating a container array for different things with different shapes?

Comment: In both cases `np.array` is fudging. In the second it makes a 2 element object array, with (1,) and (2,2) arrays. In the first the combination of (1,) and (1,2) takes a different path and ends in an error.

Comment: This is not a reliable way of making an object array with an arbitrary mix of inputs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885508/why-do-i-get-error-trying-to-cast-np-arraysome-list-valueerror-could-not-broa for a more detailed explanation.  And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117632/creating-array-of-arrays-in-numpy-with-different-dimensions

Comment: @hpaulj what's problem with creating array of some different things in numpy?

Comment: Read the duplicates

Comment: @hpaulj is right, this is not idiomatic at all. Numpy may not be the tool for the job.

Comment: You can put those arrays in an object dtype array, but not with the `np.array`  function.

Answer (score 0):

If the final output can be a 1D vector, `np.append` might do the trick:

```
np.append(np.array([1]),np.array([[1,2]]))
```

If each element of the final desired array is a different dimension, do you need it to be a numpy object? a list should work `final = [np.array([1]), np.array([ [1,2], [1,2] ])]`

Comment: can you explain what's the problem with creating that array with np.array ?

Comment: numpy is trying to bring n-dimension matrix operations to python. so `results[1,4,5]` returns some number. 
Arrays must be a rectangle (2d), box (3d), n-rectangle (n-dim). When you try to combine arrays with a different shape, its like you're trying to make a box with a sheet of 1x1" paper and a 2x2'' box. They don't make a continuous object.  

in your example, if numpy were to allow you, what would `results[1,2]` mean?